# Join the Fun at Jack’s Casino to get a shot at Jackpot

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, number-sequence, no-computers

Jack’s casino dealers are not all prime. But, he gives better odds to get the daily Jackpot by revealing lot more numbers in the sequence in play. That way his Casino is much better than Cryptic Casino. He is sneaky and he wants you to reveal the number behind the sequence also prior to parting with his Jackpot.

To earn the jackpot, you have to find five missing cards of the daily sequence and place them in the right spot.

Today’s sequence deck consists of 42 cards. No kings, queens and jacks. 2 jokers are added to represent the extra cards 3 and 6.

Ace is represented  by 1.  Suits are...S..spades C..clubs D..Diamonds  H..hearts  JJ..joker   0...stands for 10.

MM...represents the 5 missing cards yo have to figure out

Cards are arranged in fours. Sequence runs from top left to right and the left to right as you go down the sequence.

Ready..set..go....here is the sequence

```
S S H S  H M S S  J S H D  S J H H
1 5 5 7  7 M 3 9  J 4 3 7  6 J 8 1

H D D C   M D H D  S H D M  S D C D
9 5 9 7   M 8 4 4  2 2 1 M  0 3 5 6

D C C C   C H C D   M M
2 3 6 1   8 0 4 0   M M
```

Good Luck...Go for the Jackpot..
Don’t forget to give the sequence number.

Since  this problem is tough , I am going to provide hints periodically.

Hint 1:

> The code is based on the reciprocal of 49 which contains periodic 42 digits.

Hint 2:

> 

Hint 3:

> 

Comment: This puzzle is based on the reciprocal of numbers with repetitive periods. I will provide hints periodically to hasten puzzle resolution. First Hint is Given today.

Comment: congrats on 1k reputation!

Comment: @Omega..thx very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing cards are:

> `SCHCC`
>  `89620`

The complete sequence is:

> `SSHS HSSS JSHD SJHH HDDC CDHD SHDH SDCD DCCC CHCD CC`
>  `1557 7839 J437 6J81 9597 9844 2216 0356 2361 8040 20`

Explanation:

> 1/49 is 0.020408163265306122448979591836734693877551...
>  
>  You reverse the periodic sequence and get
>  
>  `155778396437638195979844221603562361804020`, which is the order of the card values.
>  
>  The order of the suits is `SHDC`. Putting them in for each number
>  gives the final card sequence.

Comment: Congrats..head fast to Cryptic Casino for furthering your luck..word spreads fast in the Casino community.....they can easily tilt the odds in their favor by simply Chang the natural sequence of the suits.